# Charts not being displayed in django app when using Chart.js 3.6 version

Tags: django, chart.js

I have a Django application which has charts. They were implement in Chart.js 2.9 version. When I upgraded to Chart.js 3.6 version, I am unable to view the charts. I have check those charts in a standalone HTML page. They work fine there.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that you might import it on the wrong way but without any code it's hard to help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved on removing the global defaults for font family, font size and font family.